# async.waterfall top level exception handler not working properly with async

Tags: javascript, express

im trying to make a top level exception handler to catches error from async.waterfall however everything works fine until async is used, please help me.

```js
async function wrap(_: Function, fn: Function) {
    let result: any = null;

    try {
        result = await fn(); // crashes when await is used
    } catch (err) {
        _(err);
    }

    _(null, result);
}
```

```js
export default function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
    try {
        waterfall([
            (next: Function) => {
                wrap(next, async () => {
                    await delay(10000);

                    return true;
                });
            },
            (a: boolean, next: Function) => {
                wrap(next, () => {
                    if (a)
                        throw new Error('Error', 500); // should get catched by main try catch
                });
            }
        ], (err: any) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
        });
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main try catch was causing the request to stop the whole server. Removing it and using "next" instead solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).